# setInterval is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, emoticons

## What this is all about

I am currently working on a script for emoticons on the Campfire Chat Service since they don't have an emoticon feature. Right now it is running the emoticon really slowly since it uses a setInterval that is suppose to check ever 200 milliseconds if there is a new message in the chat. I do this by making two variables "a" and "b" with `var a,b;`. So then in the first setInterval I time it with **150** millisecond. Inside of this I just give the variable "a" the value of the HTML of the chat. Then in the second setInterval (200) I give the variable "b" the value of the HTML too but this is a different timing so now I check the HTML in an `if` statement and if it is different I run the function to change the Symbol to an emoticon. I did it this was to improve performance. Before it would check for emoticons even though no one in the Campfire Chat actually wrote something so there is no need to check for emoticons.

This is the complete function:

```
var a, b;
setInterval(function() {
    a = $('#chat').html();
    console.warn("Chat HTML has been Scanned");
}, 150);
var t = "0";
setInterval(function() {
    b = $('#chat').html();
    console.warn("Chat got scanned for Change in html.");
    if (emoOn == true) {
        if (t === $('#num12345').text()) {
            $(".participants").after('<div id="emote"><h3><span class="room_actions"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="on" style="font-weight:bold;">On</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="off" style="cursor:pointer;">Off</a></span>Emoticons</h3></div>');
            $('#num12345').text("111")
        }
        if (a !== b) {
            turnOn();
            console.log("CHANGE")
        } else {
            turnOn("off");
        }
    }
}, 200)​;
```

## **The problem**

As you can see in the above code I run 3 consoles. In the consoles I expect the "Chat HTML has been Scanned" warning to come for and then the "Chat got scanned for Change in html." in that order for the whole time. But instead the "Chat HTML has been Scanned" warning shoes up twice it just doesn't work like I image it to work.

And when a new message shows its suppose to log "Change" but most of the time it doesn't and I think it is the problem of the setIntervals. It seems like they aren't timing right. But I really don't wanna say that JavaScript is causing this issue but I don't know what else it could be. Also I'm using Chrome.

Comment: @undefined The OP didn't say he doesn't like it. And also, `setInterval()` is not a human being.

Comment: @Nathan, sry, i was joking, of course it's not a human being

Comment: @undefined Oh ok, it's all good :)

Comment: Assume that `setInterval`, a function used by millions of web sites, is working correctly and your code is at fault.

Comment: @EdS. Good to know? Ok then if my code is at fault and you seem to be so smart how about you find something wrong with my code. I would appreciate that. You people on this site are just some real.........sometimes.

Comment: @Shawn31313: I don't know, I only know that the error is far, far more likely to be in your code.

Comment: Yes. I do know that. Well anyways already found a fix for it from a Good answer on my other post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setInterval is asynchronous, so when your first call is waiting, the javascript interpreter moves on to it's next job (in this case setting t to "0" and then your second setInterval call).

Edit: I think the problem is that you're defining your setInterval calls at the same time, yet the precision of javascript timers is not that great (see here: http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/).

You could call the second setInterval after a setTimeout to give yourself a bit of a buffer:

```
var a, b;
setInterval(function() {
    a = $('#chat').html();
    console.warn("Chat HTML has been Scanned");
    var t = "0";
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        b = $('#chat').html();
        console.warn("Chat got scanned for Change in html.");
        if (emoOn == true) {
            if (t === $('#num12345').text()) {
                $(".participants").after('<div id="emote"><h3><span class="room_actions"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="on" style="font-weight:bold;">On</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="off" style="cursor:pointer;">Off</a></span>Emoticons</h3></div>');
                $('#num12345').text("111")
            }
            if (a !== b) {
                turnOn();
                console.log("CHANGE")
            } else {
                turnOn("off");
            }
        }
    }, 2000)​;

}, 500);
```

This will set up the second call to setInterval half a second after the first, you could get away with a lot less than that though (anything over 30ms should be enough).

Comment: This makes everything worse..the "Chat got scanned for Change in html." warning now shows up about 80 times and then the other one.

Comment: wait a minute, are you expecting each setInterval call to run only once? setInterval will run every x milliseconds, so the function in your second setInterval call will execute ten times a second. setTimeout will execute just once if that's what you're after.

Comment: No I dont want it to just run once. I want it to switch but right now it is doing one warning then there other one like 80 times and then that one warning again. But I got it work. But right now the first 2 warnings work fine but now after the 2nd warnign they both appear quickly after each other which it didnt do before

Comment: Okay, so ignore my answer, going back to your original code, you have one timeout set to 2000, and the other to 200, is this a typo?

Comment: oh yes. Sorry i fixed that now.

Comment: I updated the answer to delay the second call, did that help?

Comment: No this doesnt help. It actually works fine but then It only works twice and then onlu the first console works -_-

Comment: Weird, just to test this myself I set up a simple page with that js in, and it worked as you'd expect. I noticed when I pasted the code into vim, there was an odd character here: }, 200)​; (the closing bracket seems to be a special character of some kind), that may be causing your problem? Otherwise there's something going wrong with the code in the if(emoOn == true) block.